# How to do auto cross-repo builds and push Docker image to AWS ECR with Github Actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, github, github-actions, amazon-ecr

I am new to docker and github actions. I have a main repo, say **Main** repo, and **Main** repo is dependent on some child repos.

[image: Repository dependency tree]

I want to build and push docker image of **Main** repo to Amazon ECR whenever there are any new pushes in develop branch of any repo(Main Repo, Child Repo 1, Child Repo 2, etc). However for that to happen I will have to first build the dependent child repos. I am unsure about how I can achieve this. Is github actions right way to go or should I look somewhere else?